# Starting gscam node (for webcam images) in ROS by using roslaunch?

Tags: ros

When i start gscam in separate terminal's window then it works fine. But i need to start 3 nodes by using roslaunch including gscam. But then i get an **error:  Failed to PAUSE stream, check your gstreamer configuration.**

I have already kept the following gscam_config in my .bash

```
GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace
```

My roslaunch file is:

```
<launch>
  <env name="GSCAM_CONFIG" value="v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace"/>
  <node pkg="gscam" type="gscam" name="gscam" /> 
</launch>
```

I have also tried:

```
<launch>

  <node pkg="gscam" type="gscam" name="gscam" GSCAM_CONFIG" value="v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace" /> 
</launch>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but I do see a few things.  You have no closing " where you stored GSCAM_CONFIG in your .bashrc

Also, why save it as video0 then restart it as video2?

From what I've seen, your error points to a permissions issue.  I've had this sort of thing happen a lot with USB devices.

Try:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/video2
```